# Combining Measures into a single column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a straightforward method for combining multiple columns of data into a single column so the data rows overlap? This is NFL data and I'd like to see the teams overlap instead of in there own separate columns. Thanks for any guidance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you place a discrete field on the Columns shelf, headers for the members of that discrete field are created. When you place that discrete field into the Marks Shelf instead (Color, Size, Detail, Tooltip...), you separate the marks in the data view according to the members of that discrete field. This is a way to show more data without changing the table structure.

You've placed `[Offense]` in the Columns shelf, and you can see that each member of `[Offense]`  (ARI/ATL/BAL...) has its own header in the table. Try removing `[Offense]` from the Columns shelf and instead adding it to Color. You'll now have a view with a single column in which the `SUM([Total Yards])` has been separated into a line per team, each a different color. If you want them all to be the same color, you can just place `[Offense]` into Detail to separate the marks without changing their appearance.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation Andrew, I clearly understood your answer and it worked exactly as I wanted. Do you have any personal recommendations for tableau resources for learning this software?